# Setting java variables affected my system variables

Tags: windows-7

Initially i was using **windows xp** in which i used to set path and class path by directing it to bin and lib folder. I did the same thing in **windows 7** by setting the environment variable name as **path** and address as the java bin folder. But this overwrote the system **path** variable. Now common comand prompt functions like notepad,ipconfig and many other things are not working. Eg. **'ipconfig'** is not recognised as an internal or external command. How to resolve it??

Comment: This question is not related with Java at all.

Comment: This happened because instead of appending to the existing text, *you* overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with re-adding the following paths to your `PATH` variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

This constitutes the bare minimum and should reflect a freshly installed Windows 7. Here's a step-by-step instruction:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>
2. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
3. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and edit the entry
4. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the above paths.